# Angular 6 load data into multi-select

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I have a simple multi-select

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select placeholder="Category 1" [formControl]="Category1" (selectionChange)="PopulateCategoryArray('Category 1', $event.value)" multiple>
<mat-option *ngFor="let subCat1 of SubCategories1; " [value]="subCat1">{{subCat1.Name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I want to if the user updates their profile, load the categories they have already selected into the multi-select, and check them to show that they have selected the options, as well as show the rest of the options so they can select more if they want to.

I have variables with the data in them.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is the problem  that you geeting

Comment: When I load the list again I don't know how to mark the ones that were selected.

Comment: can you share your ts file code to (SubCategories1) this list output